# Can you please tell me what is this peice of code doing?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-ads-api

I have a website which i used to get traffic through google ads, but google continously disapprove my ads. even my competitior is running successfully.

they have this peice of code. can you please tell me what is this `JOLLYWALLET_mainScript` , any idea ?

```
<script type="text/css" src="about:blank" class="JOLLYWALLET_mainScript" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79"></script>
```

i know this is very large code, but if you can give me a little hint. i will be thankful

tl:dr;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; height: 100%;">
    <!--
<head>
-->
<head show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79">
<!--
<head>
-->
    <!-- START HEADER -->
            <script type="text/css" src="about:blank" class="JOLLYWALLET_mainScript" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79">
        var foundPUP = 0;
    </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79">
        window.FoxyDeal = {};
        window.Pricescout = {};

        window.onerror=function(msg, url, linenumber){
            console.log("JSError: "+msg+"<*>"+url+"<*>"+linenumber);
            return true;
        };

        function strip(html){
            var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
            tmp.innerHTML = html;
            return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
        }

        var DomChanges = (function() {
            "appendChild removeChild insertBefore insertAfter insertAttribute removeAttribute replaceChild createElement"
                .split(" ")
                .forEach(
                function ( ftype ) {
                    var corefn = this[ftype];
                    this[ftype] = function () {
                        var whiteList =  false;

                        var scriptDef = "";
                        if (arguments[0].src){
                            scriptDef = arguments[0].src;
                        }else if (arguments[0].innerHTML){
                            scriptDef = arguments[0].innerHTML;
                        }

                        scriptDef = scriptDef.toLowerCase();

                        if (arguments[0].src){
                            if (arguments[0].src.indexOf("privacy-policy.truste.com") > -1 || arguments[0].src.indexOf("cdn.ywxi.net") > -1 ||
                                arguments[0].src.indexOf("connect.facebook.net") > -1 || arguments[0].src.indexOf("stats.g.doubleclick.net") > -1 ||
                                arguments[0].src.indexOf("googleadservices.com") > -1 ||
                                arguments[0].src.indexOf("bc585587b3ada44fb186-a46329c63c211af5793807450e90a072.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com") > -1 ||
                                arguments[0].src.indexOf("seal.websecurity.norton.com") > -1 ||
                                arguments[0].src.indexOf("cdn.inspectlet.com") > -1 ||
                                arguments[0].src.indexOf("www.google-analytics.com") > -1 || arguments[0].src.indexOf("googletagmanager.com") > -1
                                || arguments[0].src.indexOf("cdnrep.reimage.com") > -1 ||  arguments[0].src.indexOf("cdnrep.reimageplus.com") > -1                            ){
                                whiteList = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (arguments[0].nodeName && arguments[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'iframe' &&
                            arguments[0].src && arguments[0].src.indexOf("javascript:false") > -1
                        ){
                            whiteList = true;
                        }

                        if (scriptDef.indexOf("javascript:false") > -1 && scriptDef.indexOf("name=\"fb") > -1){
                            whiteList = true;
                        }

                        if (    scriptDef.indexOf("var imgurl") > -1 ||
                                scriptDef.indexOf("fancyisopen = false") > -1 ||
                                scriptDef.indexOf("fancybox-margin") > -1 ||
                                scriptDef.indexOf("fancybox-skin") > -1 ||
                                scriptDef.indexOf("6-3fckyd8weqkpqm7wm") > -1 ||
                                scriptDef.indexOf("gorepair()") > -1 ||
                                scriptDef.indexOf("class=\"ie9\"") > -1 ||
                                scriptDef.indexOf("class=\"download-link") > -1 ||
                                scriptDef.indexOf("rel=\"gorepair\"") > -1
                             || scriptDef.indexOf("ua-24411584-1") > -1                        ){
                            whiteList = true;
                        }

                        if (arguments[0].nodeName && arguments[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'script' && arguments[0].hasAttribute("show")){
                            whiteList = true;
                        }

                        if (arguments[0].nodeName && arguments[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'div' && arguments[0].hasAttribute("show")){
                            whiteList = true;
                        }

                        if (arguments[0].nodeName && arguments[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'iframe' && arguments[0].hasAttribute("show")){
                            whiteList = true;
                        }

                        if (scriptDef == "" ||
                            scriptDef == "<div></div>" ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"height: 99px;") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("a name=\"script") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("a name=\"sizcache") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("a name=\"sizzle") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"padding: 1px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; display: block; overflow: visible; width: 1px; zoom: 1;\"><div style=\"width: 5px;\"></div></div>") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div classname=\"t\"") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"display: inline; margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 1px; width: 1px; zoom: 1;\"></div>") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"box-sizing") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 1px; border: 0px currentcolor; border-image: none; width: 1px; display: inline; -ms-zoom: 1;\"></div>") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 1px; border: 0px currentcolor; width: 1px; display: inline; zoom: 1;\"></div>") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px currentcolor; width: 1px; display: block; box-sizing: content-box; -moz-box-sizing: content-box; -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;\"><table><tbody><tr><td style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px currentcolor;\"></td><td style=\"display: none;\">t</td></tr></tbody></table></div>") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px currentcolor; border-image: none; width: 1px; display: block; box-sizing: content-box; -moz-box-sizing: content-box; -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;\"><table><tbody><tr><td style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px currentcolor; border-image: none;\"></td><td style=\"display: none;\">t</td></tr></tbody></table></div>") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 1px; border: 0px currentcolor; width: 1px; display: inline; -ms-zoom: 1;\"></div>") > -1 ||
                            (scriptDef.indexOf("border: 0px currentcolor") > -1 && scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"width: 5px;\"></div>") > -1) ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("onfocusin=\"t\" onchange=\"t\" onsubmit=\"t\" classname=\"t") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px none; display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 1px;\"><div style=\"padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px none; display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 0px;\"></div></div>") > -1 ||
                            (scriptDef.indexOf("<link>") > -1 && scriptDef.indexOf("top: 1px; float: left; opacity: 0.5;") > -1 && scriptDef.indexOf("<input type=\"checkbox\">") > -1) ||
                            (scriptDef.indexOf("zoom: 1; display: block;") > -1 && scriptDef.indexOf("<div style=\"width: 5px; \"></div>") > -1) ||
                            (scriptDef.indexOf("padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px none; display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 1px;") > -1 && scriptDef.indexOf("padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px none; display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 0px;") > -1) ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("display: inline; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; border-image: initial; padding-top: 1px; padding-right: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; padding-left: 1px; width: 1px; zoom: 1;") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("pd-float-tm") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("mcafeesecure.com/verify-float") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("browse safer with our") > -1 ||
                            scriptDef.indexOf("cdn.ywxi.net") > -1 || scriptDef.indexOf("www.googletagmanager.com") > -1 ||
                            (scriptDef.indexOf("customevent") > -1 && scriptDef.indexOf("tvtretrievedvariablesevent") > -1)
                        ){
                            whiteList = true;
                        }

                        if (whiteList){
                            DomChangeA( ftype, arguments );
                            return corefn.apply( this, arguments );
                        }else{
                            DomChange( ftype, arguments );
                            return;
                        }
                    };
                },
                Element.prototype
            );

            function DomChange (ftype, arguments) {
                foundPUP++;
                            };

            function DomChangeA (ftype, arguments) {
                            };
        }());
            </script>
      <title show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79">Reimage Repair - Speed up my PC</title>
  <meta show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--
</head>
-->
</head>
<!--
</head>
-->
<!-- END HEADER --> <body id="mainBody" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79" style="margin: -1px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px; overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; height: 100%;">
     <iframe id="mainFrame" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79" hidden="false" sab="1" replaced="true" yvp_visible="true" nuan_newframe="true" abp="1" xyz-handled="" xyz-ad="1" kwframeid="1" __idm_frm__="1" src="index_src.php?channel=direct&banner=direct&adgroup=direct&ads_name=direct&keyword=direct&nms=1" frameborder="0" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 2147483647;" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
        <!-- START BODY -->                    <script type="text/javascript" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79">
            var popit = true;
            window.onbeforeunload = function(index) {
                if(popit == true) {
                    popit = false;
                                        return "Wait! Don’t leave us just yet!  Press stay on this page to Run a FREE Scan of your PC now and to decide to purchase the full version later!";
                }
            }
        </script>
    
<script type="text/javascript" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79">
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        jQuery('[show!="on"]').hide();
        jQuery('[show!="on"]').remove();
        jQuery('#mainBody').css({'top' : '0px', 'margin' : '-1px 0px 0px 0px', 'padding' : '1px 0px 0px 0px'});
        jQuery('#mainFrame').css({'top' : '0px', 'z-index' : '2147483647'});

        jQuery('#mainFrame').css({'display' : 'block', 'visibility' : 'visible'});
        jQuery('#mainFrame').show();
        jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("wothidden", "block");
        document.getElementById('mainFrame').hidden = false;
        jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("sab", "1");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("replaced", "true");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("yvp_visible", "true");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("nuan_newframe", "true");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("abp", "1");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("xyz-handled", "");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("kwframeid", "1");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("__idm_frm__", "100");

        jQuery('#mainFrame').addClass("mp4downloader_tagChecked ");

        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("type");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("allowscriptaccess");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("selected");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_id");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_position");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_zindex");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_top");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_bottom");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_left");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_right");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_visible");
        jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("mytubeid");

        var count = 0;
        var iframeHidden = false;
        var intEr = setInterval(function () {
            jQuery('[show!="on"]').hide();
            jQuery('[show!="on"]').remove();
            jQuery('#mainBody').css({'top' : '0px', 'margin' : '-1px 0px 0px 0px', 'padding' : '1px 0px 0px 0px'});
            jQuery('#mainFrame').css({'top' : '0px', 'z-index' : '2147483647'});

            jQuery('#mainFrame').css({'display' : 'block', 'visibility' : 'visible'});
            jQuery('#mainFrame').show();
            jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("wothidden", "block");
            document.getElementById('mainFrame').hidden = false;
            jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("sab", "1");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("replaced", "true");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("yvp_visible", "true");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("nuan_newframe", "true");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("abp", "1");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("xyz-handled", "");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("xyz-ad", '1');
            jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("kwframeid", "1");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').attr("__idm_frm__", "100");

            jQuery('#mainFrame').addClass("mp4downloader_tagChecked ");

            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("type");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("allowscriptaccess");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("selected");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_id");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_position");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_zindex");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_top");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_bottom");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_left");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_right");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("yvp_visible");
            jQuery('#mainFrame').removeAttr("mytubeid");

            var iframeOuter = document.getElementById('mainFrame').outerHTML;

            /*alert("ORG - "+iframeOuterOrg);
             alert("Interval - "+iframeOuter);*/

            if (count> 5 && !iframeHidden && (document.getElementById('mainFrame').hidden || document.getElementById('mainFrame').style.display == "none" || document.getElementById('mainFrame').style.visibility == "hidden")) {

                /*if (count> 5 && !iframeHidden && iframeOuterOrg != iframeOuter && iframeOuter.indexOf("overflow:") > -1 && ){*/
                                
                jQuery.get("/includes/set_javascript.php?error=iframeProblemHidden7&htmlOrg="+iframeOuterOrg+"&htmlAfter="+iframeOuter, function (data) {
                    /* Ajax complete */
                });

                iframeHidden = true;
            }
            count++;
        }, 1*100);

        setTimeout(function () {
            clearInterval(intEr);
        }, 10*1000);
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79">
    function removeINJ(){
        if (document.getElementById("__modal_container")){
            foundPUP++;
            var node = document.getElementById("__modal_container");
            node.style.display = 'none';
            if (node.parentNode) {
                try {
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                }
                catch(err) {
                    /*alert(err.message);*/
                }
            }
        }

        if (document.getElementById("affiliateToolbarDiv")){
            foundPUP++;
            var node = document.getElementById("affiliateToolbarDiv");
            node.style.display = 'none';
            if (node.parentNode) {
                try {
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                }
                catch(err) {
                    /*alert(err.message);*/
                }
            }
        }

        if (document.getElementById("jwbar")){
            foundPUP++;
            var node = document.getElementById("jwbar");
            node.style.display = 'none';
            if (node.parentNode) {
                try {
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                }
                catch(err) {
                    /*alert(err.message);*/
                }
            }
        }

        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
        for (var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
            var keepEl = scripts[i].hasAttribute ? scripts[i].hasAttribute("show") : scripts[i]["show"] !== undefined;

            if (!keepEl){
                var node = scripts[i];
                if (node.src && (
                    node.src.indexOf("privacy-policy.truste.com") > -1 || node.src.indexOf("cdn.ywxi.net") > -1 ||
                    node.src.indexOf("connect.facebook.net") > -1 || node.src.indexOf("stats.g.doubleclick.net") > -1 ||
                    node.src.indexOf("googleadservices.com") > -1 ||
                    node.src.indexOf("bc585587b3ada44fb186-a46329c63c211af5793807450e90a072.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com") > -1 ||
                    node.src.indexOf("seal.websecurity.norton.com") > -1 || node.src.indexOf("googleadservices.com") > -1 ||
                    node.src.indexOf("cdn.inspectlet.com") > -1 ||
                    node.src.indexOf("www.google-analytics.com") > -1 || node.src.indexOf("googletagmanager.com") > -1
                        || node.src.indexOf("cdnrep.reimage.com") > -1 ||  node.src.indexOf("cdnrep.reimageplus.com") > -1                    )){
                    break;
                }

                foundPUP++;

                
                node.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                node.setAttribute("src", "about:blank");

                if (node.parentNode) {
                    try {
                        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                    }
                    catch(err) {
                        /*alert(err.message);*/
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        for (var i=0; i<iframes.length; i++) {
            var node = iframes[i];
            var keepEl = node.hasAttribute ? node.hasAttribute("show") : node["show"] !== undefined;

            if (!keepEl){
                if (node.src){
                    if (node.src.indexOf("www.mcafeesecure.com/verify-float") > -1 || node.src.indexOf("www.googleadservices.com") > -1){
                        break;
                    }
                }

                foundPUP++;

                
                node.setAttribute("src", "about:blank");
                if (node.parentNode) {
                    try {
                        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                    }
                    catch(err) {
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    var iframeOuterOrg = "";
    (function() {
        iframeOuterOrg = document.getElementById('mainFrame').outerHTML;
        removeINJ();

        var intIF1 = setInterval(function () {
            removeINJ();
        }, 1*100);

        setTimeout(function () {
            clearInterval(intIF1);
        }, 10*1000);
    })();

    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        removeINJ();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" show="on" nonce="2f878f051eca5796ab6e931026341c79">
    (function() {
        if (window.jQuery) {
                                }
    })();
</script>

<!--
</body>
-->
</body>
<!--
</body>
-->
<!-- END BODY --></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for something related to ad. Like for ad banners or something like this. If you won't post any ad on your site, you can delete this script

Comment: it will block ads on their website?

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe